# AWS Domain Path Routing to ECS Service listening on specific port

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53

Is there any way in AWS to create specific rules and have an application path point to a service running in an ECS cluster on a specific port. For example:

ECS-Cluster (abc.test.com)

- Service 1 : Listening on port 8081 (abc.test.com:8081)
- Service 2 : Listening on port 8082 (abc.test.com:8082)

I would want like it to be configured to achieve below:

- abc.test.com/path1/* -->> abc.test.com:8081
- abc.test.com/path2/* -->> abc.test.com:8082

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your service in ECS.

At **Step 2: Configure network** => **Container to load balance**

Set your **Path pattern**

[image: Capture of my Service]